# Smartwatch 2 Control API change text size programatically

Tags: text, size, sony, sony-smartwatch

I need to set the Font Size of a ViewText on the onCreate/onResume method..

I think it must be this way:

```
public void onResume() {
     Bundle LayoutData = new Bundle();
     LayoutData.putInt(Control.Intents.EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_ID, MENU_ITEM_1);
     **(line missing)** 
     showLayout(R.layout.text_view, LayoutData);  

....
}
```

I am missing this:  I can''t find the option for EXTRA_FONT_SIZE, like the EXTRA_TEXT for the intent.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that by sending a constant.  If you want to change the text size of the TextView then you have to create a new layout or alter your existing one and then call showLayout() again.  So if you are using an XML layout then you can either create a 2nd layout the same as the first but with a different font size for the TextView or if you are creating your TextView in the code then call setTextSize() on the TextView and then call showLayout().

Comment: Thanks! I will use multiple layouts!